# Using testing-library findby* queries with @badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor

Tags: cucumber, cypress, cypress-cucumber-preprocessor, cypress-testing-library

I have a react app that I'm trying to test with Cypress using the `badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor` and `testing-library` but I'm getting the error

```js
cy.findByRole is not a function
```

Here's my current setup:

- react-scripts: 5.0.1
- typescript: 4.8.3
- cypress: 10.8.0
- @badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor: 12.2.0
- @testing-library/cypress: 8.0.3
- node: 16.15.0

I have created a sample app that demonstrates the issue [here](https://github.com/ericcmmi/test-all-things)

The e2e section of `cypress.config.ts` has two configurations that can be tested by commenting out one and leaving the other. The first (as it is currently configured) will attempt to run the test as a feature file and will fail. The second configuration uses a normal cypress test and will show that the `testing-library function works correctly there.

The `setupNodeEvents()` function in `cypress.config.ts` doesn't exactly follow the webpack/ts example found in the badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor docs because that example doesn't play well with esModuleInterop being set to true which is used in other parts of my app so this configuration is my attempt to make that work. But I did test that example configuration and still couldn't get the testing-library functions to work.

I have the scripts setup so you can use **npm test** to start cypress in e2e mode.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

@Tiana is correct, but in addition you have set `supportFile: false` in configuration, so the import you have in `support/commands.ts` will never be used.

**cypress.config.ts**

```js
export default defineConfig({
  ...
  e2e: {
    specPattern: "**/*.feature",

    supportFile: false,        <-- don't do this if you want to use the support file
    setupNodeEvents,
  },
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Cypress allows you to add common code for each step file by putting it into `cypress/support/e2e.js`.

If you add  `import "@testing-library/cypress/add-commands"` there, you will get the `cy.findByRole()` command in every spec.

`cypress/support/e2e.js` acts like a "header" for every spec. Using the cucumber library on top of Cypress does not remove that facility.

Answer (score 0):

Adding import "@testing-library/cypress/add-commands"; to each of the step files seems to work. Didn't recognize the import from cypress/support/commands.ts.